# Live-Reload in Nitrous

Tags: ember.js, nitrousio

I can't use live reload in an Ember application which runs on [nitrous.io](http://www.nitrous.io). I get the following error message:

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the script 
'http://ember-js-126346.nitrousapp.com:49152/livereload.js?snipver=1' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' localhost:49152 0.0.0.0:49152 
localhost:49152 0.0.0.0:49152".
```

[image: screenshot of the error message]

What do I have to change to get live reloading going in this setup?

Comment: Is your port open, and did you click on the Preview>Port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-inject-live-reload and making sure you set `EMBER_CLI_INJECT_LIVE_RELOAD_HOST`.

Comment: How and where do I have to configure EMBER_CLI_INJECT_LIVE_RELOAD_HOST? I can't find any documentation.